# remove specific file form multiple file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I implemented a following HTML `<input>` multiple Attribute

```
 <input type="file" name="R" id="someattachId" multiple="multiple" style='display:none' />
```

I'm trying to remove specific item in it using following code

```
$('#someattachId')[0].files[fileId].remove();
```

but it can't remove it.

Comment: You can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943605/remove-a-filelist-item-from-a-multiple-inputfile

Comment: Try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control

Comment: @DanielLagiň how can I access thos file `validatedFiles` in server side then

Answer (score 2):

No, We can make it removable.
I implemented this and it works definitely.

First you need to initialize this variables

```
var newImageObj = [];
var ImageNo = 0;
```

Then write this code on file input's change

```
$("#exampleInputFileProduct").change(function () {

            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("exampleInputFileProduct");

            //$("#mainImages").html('');
            //$("#subImages").html('');

            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

                //Here Check File Extension
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png)$/;


                for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.files.length; i++) {
                    var j = 0;
                    var file = fileUpload.files[i];
                    var NewFile = fileUpload.files[i];
                    //Here Check File Size 1MB = 1000000 Bytes
                    if (file.size < 2048000) {
                        if (regex.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (e) {

                                if ($("#mainImages").find(".item").attr("id") == "FirstSlider") {
                                    $("#mainImages").html('');
                                    $("#subImages").html('');
                                    $("#subImages").append("<div class='item active'></div>");
                                }

                                if ($("#mainImages").find(".item").hasClass("active")) {
                                    $("#mainImages").append("<div class='item " + ImageNo + "_CClass\'><i class='fa fa-times customIcon' onclick='RemoveImage(\"" + ImageNo + "_CClass\",\"" + fileUpload.files[j].name.toLowerCase() + "\")'></i><img class='CImage' src='" + e.target.result + "' alt='' /></div>");
                                } else {
                                    $("#mainImages").append("<div class='item active " + ImageNo + "_CClass'><i class='fa fa-times customIcon' onclick='RemoveImage(\"" + ImageNo + "_CClass\",\"" + fileUpload.files[j].name.toLowerCase() + "\")'></i><img class='CImage' src='" + e.target.result + "' alt='' /></div>");
                                }

                                //if ($("#subImages").find(".item").length == 0) {
                                //    $("#subImages").append("<div class='item active'></div>");
                                //} else {
                                if (($("#subImages").find(".item").find("div").length / 5) >= $("#subImages").find(".item").length) {
                                    $("#subImages").append("<div class='item'></div>");
                                }
                                //}

                                var append = 0;

                                $.each($("#subImages").find(".item"), function (p, pelement) {
                                    if (append == 0) {
                                        if ($(pelement).find("div").length != 5) {
                                            var newID = $(pelement).find("div").length;
                                            newID = newID;
                                            $(pelement).append("<div onclick='LoadImage(\"" + ImageNo + "_CClass\")' data-slide-to='" + newID + "' class='thumb " + ImageNo + "_CClass'> <img src='" + e.target.result + "' alt=''></div>");
                                            append = append + 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                })

                                j = j + 1;

                                ImageNo = ImageNo + 1;
                            }

                            newImageObj.push(file);

                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
            }
        });
```

Then at last this 2 functions will help to do the rest

```
function LoadImage(objclass) {
            $("#mainImages").find(".item").removeClass("active");
            $("#mainImages").find("." + objclass + "").addClass("active");
        }

        function RemoveImage(objclass, ImageName) {

            $.each(newImageObj, function (e, element) {
                if ($(this)[0].name.toLowerCase().trim() == ImageName.trim()) {
                    newImageObj.pop(this);
                }
            });

            $("#mainImages").find("." + objclass + "").remove();
            $("#subImages").find(".item").find("." + objclass + "").remove();

            if ($("#mainImages").find(".item").length == 0) {
                $("#mainImages").append("<div class='item active'><i class='fa fa-times customIcon'></i><img class='CImage' src='/Content/img/DefaultProduct.gif' alt='' /></div>");
                $("#subImages").append("<div class='item active'><div data-target='#carousel' data-slide-to='0' class='thumb'> <img src='/Content/img/DefaultProduct.gif' alt=''></div></div></div>");
            } else {
                $("#mainImages").find(".item").removeClass("active");
                $("#mainImages").find(".item:first-child").addClass("active");
                $("#subImages").find(".item").removeClass("active");
                $("#subImages").find(".item:first-child").addClass("active");
            }
        }
```

At last when you submit your form than take the files from the array