# How to delete from an object FileList

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The function of this code, the preview image is displayed after selecting the file. Also internally, each key and value is inserted into the FileList object.
Each image displayed as a preview has a delete button. So, when you press it, the image disappears from the screen, and internally, I want to delete the corresponding key and value from the FileList object. I knew that I could delete from Object, like a " delete Object.key ; "  However, in this case, this does not work effectively. Perhaps there are other different solutions to it. Please let me know if you know if

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style>
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
</style>

<form id='form' action="data.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<button class="show">Butoon</button>
</form>


<output id="list"></output>

<script>

  $('output').on('click','.del',function(){
    var id = $(this).prev().attr('id');
    id = id.split("_");
    id=  id[1];

    var x = document.getElementById("files").files;

    if(id in x) {
     delete x[' + id + '];　　//This line is a problem.
    } 
     console.dir(x);

    $(this).parent().replaceWith();
  });

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (function(theFile, num) {
        return function(e) {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<div class="view"><img id ="img_' + num + ' " class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><div class="del">×</div></div>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f, i);
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
      console.dir(files);
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just think you may find this answer helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943605/remove-a-filelist-item-from-a-multiple-inputfile/47642446#47642446

Answer (score 0):

Replace delete x[' + id + ']; with:

x.splice(id,1);

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it, but I couldn't.